# ¿Cómo hacer notificación tipo Facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

¿Cómo hacer una notificación al estilo Facebook cuando hay un cambio en la base de datos MySQL? Que la página refresque el número de notificación y lo cambie a otro, y mientras ese no sea leído, no desaparezca.

Lo necesito para más de 2 items, es decir uno para notificaciones y otro para mensajes el que he conseguido sólo sirve para una notificación y no sé cómo separar para poder utilizar dos scripts iguales en la misma página pero que las consultas sean diferentes: una consulta que sume el número de notificaciones y la otra el número de mensajes.

Tengo esto el el index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Minimum Bootstrap HTML Skeleton</title>

    <!--  -->

    <style>
        #notification_count {
            padding: 0px 3px 3px 7px;
            background: #cc0000;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left: 77px;
            border-radius: 9px;
            -moz-border-radius: 9px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: -1px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function addmsg(type, msg) {

            $('#notification_count').html(msg);

        }

        function waitForMsg() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "select.php",

                async: true,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 50000,

                success: function(data) {
                    addmsg("new", data);
                    setTimeout(
                        waitForMsg,
                        1000
                    );
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                    setTimeout(
                        waitForMsg,
                        15000);
                }
            });
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            waitForMsg();

        });
    </script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function getNotification() {



 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "update.php", 

});




});
</script>
    <span id="notification_count"></span>
    <a href="#" id="notificationLink" onclick="return getNotification()">Notifications</a>
    <div id="HTMLnoti" style="textalign:center"></div>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

y esto en select.php

```
<?php
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "root";
       $dbname = "aaa";

       // Create connection

       $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

       // Check connection

       if ($conn->connect_error) {

           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

       } 

       $sql = "SELECT * from tbl_noti where status = 'unread'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
       $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
       $count = $result->num_rows;
       echo $count;
       $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahora mismo tu código funciona así: carga la página; la página llama a través de AJAX a select.php; select.php busca el número de notificaciones no leidas y lo devuelve como un número; el número de notificaciones se actualiza en la página; se vuelve a llamar a select.php después de X segundos, repitiendo el ciclo una y otra vez.

Ahora, lo que quieres hacer es que no sólo se actualicen las notificaciones sino también los mensajes. Eso se puede hacer de manera relativamente *sencilla*, con unos pocos cambios:

### Cambios en select.php

En lugar de hacer un único select que devuelva el número de notificaciones, haz dos select una para las notificaciones y la otra para los mensajes y en lugar de devolver un número, devuelve JSON con los contadores.

Por ejemplo (voy a simplificar el código entre otras cosas porque desconozco la estructura de tu base de datos, pero debería servirte de idea):

```
   // ... el inicio de mantiene igual

   $sql = "SELECT * from tbl_noti where status = 'unread'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $count = $result->num_rows;

   $sql2 = "SELECT * from tbl_mensajes where status = 'unread'";
   $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
   $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
   $count2 = $result2->num_rows;

   $conn->close();

   $aux = array("notif" => $count, "mensajes" => $count2);
   echo json_encode($aux);
```

Eso hará que, en lugar de devolver un número, se devuelva un objeto de la forma (por ejemplo):

```
{ "notif": 1, "mensajes": 4 }
```

Donde `notif` sería el número de notificaciones sin leer y `mensajes` sería el número de mensajes sin leer.

### Cambios en el JavaScript

Ahora lo que habría que cambiar es el resultado de cuando la petición AJAX funciona. Como ya no se devuelve un número sino un objeto con los dos valores, lo que tendrás que hacer es:

1. Parsear el resultado
2. Actualizar el número de las notificaciones (que ya hacías)
3. Actualizar el número de los mensajes (pendiente)

Centrándome sólo en el `success`, el código podría ser algo así:

```
            success: function(data) {
                // el resultado es un string, lo convertimos a un objeto
                datos = JSON.parse(data);

                // Esto se mantiene casi igual, sólo hay que cambiar el resultado leído
                addmsg("new", datos.notif);

                // y añadir algo similar para los mensajes
                $("#id_numero_mensajes").text(datos.mensajes);

                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg,
                    1000
                );
            },
```

Sé que el código puede no ser perfecto. Pero estoy seguro de que te servirá de guía y como base para continuar.

Comment: muchas gracias Alvaro me funciono una parte logre separar las dos consultas, ahora en el index.php he colocado el llamado a cada una de las variables por separado pero solo me toma la ultima tabla, quizas es la duda que tengo que no se que hacer con esto que me indicas aqui { "notif": 1, "mensajes": 4 } donde coloco esto? y quizassea este el problema

Comment: `{ "notif": 1, "mensajes": 4 }` es sólo un ejemplo de lo que podría generarse en select.php

Comment: ok solo me queda como mexclar estas dos cosas.

Comment: // Esto se mantiene casi igual, sólo hay que cambiar el resultado leído
                addmsg("new", datos.notif);

                // y añadir algo similar para los mensajes
                $("#id").text(datos.mensajes);

Comment: como o de que manera indico en estas dos filas que me tome para una variable el valor contador de la tabla messagetest y la otra lea el valor del contador de la tabla messagetest2

Comment: Ok, eso se hace en select.php. Como puedes ver en el ejemplo de arriba, las dos SELECT se hacen en select.php y luego se guardan los resultados en un array que se devuelve como JSON (`$aux = array("notif" => $count, "mensajes" => $count2); echo json_encode($aux);`). Luego en index.php se lee ese JSON (como string), se transforma a objeto JSON (usando `JSON.parse`) y ya puedes acceder a los dos valores referenciando su nombre dentro del objeto.

Comment: otra duda y disculpa esta cadena: de esto: addmsg("new", datos.notif); como junto las dos variables aqui. es decir quisiera que esten de esta forma :   addmsg("new", datos.notif);

Comment: addmsg("new", datos.notif); y addmsg("new", datos.mensajes); de que manera puedo mexclar esto en la misma linea

Comment: `datos` es un objeto que contiene `notif` y `mensajes`. Pasa `datos` directamente y luego, dentro de `addmsg(type, msg)` puedes leer `msg.notif` y `msg.mensajes`.

Comment: lo logre.. muchsimas gracias por tu consejo